# Salesforce Validation Rule to compare value of one pick-list with other pick-list

Tags: salesforce

I need to write validation rule on account, which will check valid country name from other pick list filed in exits in same object. In case that country name does not match from other country picklist then error should be displayed at account.

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below

TEXT( Field1 ) != TEXT( Field2 )

There are several functions available to use. You can find them while creating the validation rules. 
[image]